# warning: array 'alphabet' initialized by parenthesized string literal

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, initialization

In a templated function, I currently have the following line:

```
static const unsigned char alphabet[17] = 
(Uppercase) ? ("0123456789ABCDEF") : ("0123456789abcdef");
```

Where `Uppercase` is a template parameter. With `-pedantic` gcc tells me:

```
warning: array 'alphabet' initialized by parenthesized string literal 
'("0123456789abcdef")'
```

How to get rid from that message (I want the `alphabet` to be in the stack) ?

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis?

Comment: @KennyTM Although that works with GCC, the result is still invalid for exactly the same reason, and might be diagnosed similarly by other implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to make your code unambiguously valid is to use a reference to an array:

```
static const char (&alphabet)[17] = 
    (Uppercase) ? ("0123456789ABCDEF") : ("0123456789abcdef");
```

This doesn't rely on the special exception that allows a string literal to be used for array initialisation. It does, as noted by neverhoodboy, require that you deal with an array of `char`, rather than an array of `unsigned char`.

You could still use this if you really need an array of `unsigned char` by using extra helper variables:

```
static const unsigned char uppercase[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
static const unsigned char lowercase[17] = "0123456789abcdef";
static const unsigned char (&alphabet)[17] =
    (Uppercase) ? uppercase : lowercase;
```

Note: when `Uppercase` is known at compile-time (you say it is a template parameter, so it should be), you may also add the `constexpr` keyword.

Comment: `unsigned char` and `char` are distinct types, so this won't work.

Comment: @neverhoodboy Oops, right, good catch. Edited to address this.

Comment: error if ...char (&alphabet)[17] =  "0123456789ABCDEF"; can you please explain this... I'm seeing this type of declaration for the first time.

Comment: `const char (&alphabet)[17]` makes alphabet a const reference to an array of 17 chars.

Comment: @dearvivekkumar (This is not exactly how the standard says it, but is easier to understand, IMO) `const char (*alphabet)[17]` makes `*alphabet` a `const char[17]`, so makes `alphabet` a pointer to `const char[17]`. Similarly, `const char (&alphabet)[17]` makes `alphabet` a reference to `const char[17]`. You could (arguably) improve readability with typedefs: `typedef const char char_array[17]; static char_array &alphabet = ...`

Comment: In C++17 you can hopefully do `auto && x = foo ? id<unsigned char[17]>{"0123456789ABCDEF"} : id<unsigned char[17]>{"0123456789abcdef"}`. Note that, although it compiles, it is undefined behavior currently as the "temporarieness" of the second and third operands is not passed-through to the operator. This, however, seems to be fine: `template<typename T, int N> struct A { T data[N]; }; auto &&x = (foo ? A<unsigned char, 17>{{"0123456789ABCDEF"}} : A<unsigned char, 17>{{"0123456789abcdef"}}).data;` because of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#86

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb "Note that, although it compiles" -- Not for me, on GCC 4.8, even in C++1y mode (with `template <typename T> using id = T;` in the source file itself). Either way, in general that seems like a useful addition, but for this specific case, it looks to me as if it only makes the code less readable.

Comment: @hvd that seems like a faulty gcc message (perhaps caused by its C support, <strike>which doesn't allow decay on rvalue arrays</strike> apparently, C allows that too. So I don't know why GCC doesn't like it). Clang takes it (and even destroys the temporaries at the end of scope this lifetime extending it, which is not currently required). I agree that in this case it is not really useful, but it was just provided to show it works all in one line of code :))

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm not sure about C++, but C does allow decay on rvalue arrays starting with C99, and GCC supports it. (As you noticed too, I see you edited your comment.) If I have some free time later, I'll check how GCC and clang differ in C++ modes here.

Comment: @hvd do you normally say "pass by const reference" or "pass by reference to cost"?

Comment: @immibis Oh wait, sorry. I thought your comment was addressed to me, and attempted to point out a problem with my answer, and in that case, reference-which-is-const was the only reasonable interpretation. But your comment was to explain it to the OP, wasn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`("abc")` is an expression of type "array of 4 const chars", and is an lvalue.  However `("abc")` is not a string literal.  String literals are tokens, i.e. something that looks specifically like "...".  A char array can be initialized by a string literal as a special syntax, but not any arbitrary expressions of the type array of const chars.  Hence, using `("abc")` as initializer for char array is illegal.  Even if you remove the parentheses, the initializer in your case is still an expression (a conditional expression, though its type is array of const chars and it's lvalue), thus cannot be used to initialize a char array.

So I don't think there's a legal way to have `alphabet` in the stack and be initialized to one of the string literals based on a condition in a single declaration.  The reference method mentioned in the other answer initializes well, but doesn't satisfy your stack storage requirement.
**EDIT**: The second approach in the other answer serves quite well with two additional declarations as helpers.

Excerpts from the standard:

For parenthesized expression:

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression whose type and value are identical to those of the enclosed expression. The presence of parentheses does not affect whether the expression is an lvalue. The parenthesized expression can be used in exactly the same contexts as those where the enclosed expression can be used, and with the same meaning, except as otherwise indicated.

For conditional expressions:

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

For character array initialization:

> A char array (whether plain char, signed char, or unsigned char), char16_t array, char32_t array, or wchar_t array can be initialized by a narrow character literal, char16_t string literal, char32_t string literal, or wide string literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array.

Comment: A modification of the second approach in my answer to make `uppercase`, `lowercase` and `alphabet` all non-static local variables would probably work (relying on the compiler to optimise away `uppercase`/`lowercase` depending on which gets used), if the OP really does need it on the stack. (I missed that, so thanks for pointing it out, but I don't think that's what the OP meant to ask, given that the OP already used `static`.)

Comment: Your second approach serves well.  I'm sorry I didn't notice that when I wrote my answer.  Edited.

Comment: Not a problem, and the extra information in your answer still makes it a good answer. :)